# Vulkan y g++ (undefined reference to `WinMain')

Tags: windows, c++11

Acabo de bajarme la libreria gráfica de Khronos (Vulkan), y quería compilar los ejemplos para ver como funciona el API. Resultó que para compilarlos con el "makefile" (por llamarlo de alguna forma) que viene preparado con los ejemplos es neceario tener el "Visual Studio 2013" :-( cosa que no me hace mucha gracia pués ya le he cogido cariño a MinGW. Y además las librerias vienen en formato (.lib) en vez de (.a) ... La cosa es que casí he logrado compilar un ejemplo con g++ pero tengo este error.

```
C:\Users\ivan\Desktop\vulkan>g++ -m64 -std=c++11 -o 01-init_instance.o -LC:/VulkanSDK/1.1.77.0/Bin  vulkan-1.dll
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): In function `main':
C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v4-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

No tengo muy claro si es por la forma en la que estoy complando y lincando (que es la siguiente):

```
::complile
g++ -m64 -std=c++11 -c -g -Wall  -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.1.77.0/Include   -MMD -MP -MF "01-init_instance.o.d" -o 01-init_instance.o 01-init_instance.cpp

::link
g++ -m64 -std=c++11 -o 01-init_instance.o -LC:/VulkanSDK/1.1.77.0/Bin  vulkan-1.dll
```

O es que al código le falta algo, que es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <util_init.hpp>

#define APP_SHORT_NAME "vulkansamples_instance"

int sample_main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct sample_info info = {};
    init_global_layer_properties(info);

    /* VULKAN_KEY_START */

    // initialize the VkApplicationInfo structure
    VkApplicationInfo app_info = {};
    app_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    app_info.pNext = NULL;
    app_info.pApplicationName = APP_SHORT_NAME;
    app_info.applicationVersion = 1;
    app_info.pEngineName = APP_SHORT_NAME;
    app_info.engineVersion = 1;
    app_info.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_0;

    // initialize the VkInstanceCreateInfo structure
    VkInstanceCreateInfo inst_info = {};
    inst_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    inst_info.pNext = NULL;
    inst_info.flags = 0;
    inst_info.pApplicationInfo = &app_info;
    inst_info.enabledExtensionCount = 0;
    inst_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = NULL;
    inst_info.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    inst_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = NULL;

    VkInstance inst;
    VkResult res;

    res = vkCreateInstance(&inst_info, NULL, &inst);
    if (res == VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER) {
        std::cout << "cannot find a compatible Vulkan ICD\n";
        exit(-1);
    } else if (res) {
        std::cout << "unknown error\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    vkDestroyInstance(inst, NULL);

    /* VULKAN_KEY_END */

    return 0;
}
```

Todos los ejemplos vienen así, por lo visto han modificado el punto de entrada principal y lo han renombrado así:

```
int sample_main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Y al complirar el error que sale es debido a que no encuentra el punto de entrada definido por Micrisoft:

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(
  _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
  _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
  _In_ int       nCmdShow
)

{
    return 0;
}
```

Que manía con cambiar las cosas y crear incopatibilidades... con lo bien que estaba uno con el simple main() de toda la vida :-)

¿Alguien sabe cúal es el problema y cómo sulucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se lo que ellos hicieron pero pude encontrar una solución. Lo primero es compilar así porque de la otra forma sigue dando el mismo problema aunque se implemente la función WinMain.

Así para C:

```
gcc -g info.cpp -o info.exe -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.1.77.0/Include  -D_WIN32 -DVK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR -LC:/VulkanSDK/1.1.77.0/Lib vulkan-1.dll -mwindows
```

Y así para C++:

```
g++ -g info.cpp -o info.exe -IC:/VulkanSDK/1.1.77.0/Include  -D_WIN32 -DVK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR -LC:/VulkanSDK/1.1.77.0/Lib vulkan-1.dll -mwindows
```

Y lo segundo es implementar la función WinMain de esta forma.

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) 
{
    int argc;
    char **argv;

    LPWSTR *commandLineArgs = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);
    if (NULL == commandLineArgs) 
    {
        argc = 0;
    }

    if (argc > 0) 
    {
        argv = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * argc);
        if (argv == NULL) {
            argc = 0;
        } else {
            for (int iii = 0; iii < argc; iii++) {
                size_t wideCharLen = wcslen(commandLineArgs[iii]);
                size_t numConverted = 0;

                argv[iii] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (wideCharLen + 1));
                if (argv[iii] != NULL) {
                    //wcstombs_s(&numConverted, argv[iii], wideCharLen + 1, commandLineArgs[iii], wideCharLen + 1);
                    numConverted = wcstombs(argv[iii], commandLineArgs[iii], wideCharLen + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    } else 
    {
        argv = NULL;
    }


    sample_main(argc, argv);



    // Free up the items we had to allocate for the command line arguments.
    if (argc > 0 && argv != NULL) 
    {
        for (int iii = 0; iii < argc; iii++) 
        {
            if (argv[iii] != NULL) 
            {
                free(argv[iii]);
            }
        }
        free(argv);
    }

}
```

Pues eso, problema resuelto :-). Espero que a alguien mas también le sea útil.

Comment: Al compilar tu código me da el siguiente error `fatal error: unknown type name 'HINSTANCE'`

Comment: Hola!! Esta pregunta es del 2018 ya ni me acordaba que la habia hecho!! Creo que el tipo HINSTANCE esta declarado en la libreria "windows.h".... si la incluyes deberia desaparecer el problema... #include<windows.h> .... De todas formas te aconsejaria que te olvidaras de Vulcan... si quieres programar juegos o graficos mejor usa Unity o Unreal... Creeme tardarás miles de veces menos que con Vulcan  o OpenGL a pelo....  Saludos!!

Comment: Al final era que estaba cargando mal el SDL, se me arreglo añadiendo esto a mi cmake `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "-L${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/windows/SDL2/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows"`

Comment: Me alegro que lo consiguieras... Saludos!!